# Splitting a word into length combination

Tags: r, split, tokenize

I'm looking for a function in R that will given a integer allow me to split a word into that length combination but with a rolling effect.

For example `function("stackoverflow", 4)` would render:

```
c("stac", "tack", "acko", "ckov", "kove", "over", "verf", "rflo", "flow")
```

Do you guys know if that function exists or must I create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
## install.packages("zoo")

x <- unlist(strsplit("stackoverflow",""))
zoo::rollapply(x,width=4,FUN = paste0,collapse="")
# [1] "stac" "tack" "acko" "ckov" "kove" "over" "verf" "erfl" "rflo" "flow"
```

A function?

```
foo <- function(input, h) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(input,""))
  zoo::rollapply(x,width=h,FUN = paste0,collapse="")
  }

foo("stackoverflow", 4)
# [1] "stac" "tack" "acko" "ckov" "kove" "over" "verf" "erfl" "rflo" "flow"
```

---

**A benchmark**

Consider the base R approach with `substring()`:

```
foo1 <- function(input, h) substring(input, seq_len(nchar(input)-h+1),h:nchar(input))
```

Let's generate a **very long** toy character string:

```
x <- paste0(rep("a",100000), collapse="")

system.time(foo(x,4))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.280   0.004   2.288 

system.time(foo1(x,4))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 10.492   0.000  10.509
```

So, the seemingly vectorized function `substring()` is **not** efficient at all, which is an interesting observation!

Comment: Nice answer and +1. Indeed rollapply is faster for very long strings, but for 'normal' length strings the base R version is way faster (eg try `microbenchmark(foo("stackoverflow", 4), foo1("stackoverflow", 4))`). Not intended as criticism, just posting it for completeness. For long strings, it is faster to use the base R way but with `stringi::stri_sub` instead of `substring`.

Comment: Nice way around thank you. I didn't want to use a for loop so yours is way faster

Answer (score 4):

We can do it by using `base R`

```
substring(s,seq_len(nchar(s)-4+1),4:nchar(s))
```

**Data**

```
s <- "stackoverflow"
```